# Как разлогиниться отсюда (stackoverflow)?

Tags: обсуждение, аутентификация, интерфейс

Меня залогинило по гуглу в не мой пустой аккаунт, не могу из него найти выход.

Comment: кнопка "список всех сайтов" в своем аккаунте (верхний правый угол) нажмите и там будет кнопка выйти.

Comment: Это на мету вопрос

Comment: Репортнул, что вопрос больше подходит для меты

Answer (score 0):

*Профиль -> Править -> Настройки сайта (Доступ)*

Добавьте новый вход (например посредством другого почтового ящика), удалите вход с текущего ящика.